# jQuery checkbox on change does not trigger from another file's jQuery action

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I've two files `Home.js` and `header.js` in header file I can open and close my input checkbox which is sidedrawer open button. But in Home file when this `input#openSlider` id checkbox on change I want to push my home content to a bit right. My main problem is when I on change in header.js, Home.js does not trigger removeClass from it.

Here is my code;

**header.js**

```
function openSidebar() {   
        if ($('input#openSlider').is(':checked')) {
        $(".sidebar__container").addClass("sidebar__container--opened");

        if (localStorage.getItem("openedDrawer") === "true") {
            $(".blurred--background").removeClass("blurred--background--opened");
        } else {
            $(".blurred--background").addClass("blurred--background--opened");
        }

    } else {

    }
}


function closeSidebar() {
    $('input#openSlider').trigger('change')
    $(".sidebar__container").removeClass("sidebar__container--opened");
    $(".blurred--background").removeClass("blurred--background--opened");
    localStorage.setItem("openedDrawer", "false");
}
```

**Home.js**

```
$('#openSlider').on('change', function () {
    console.log('testste')
    if ($('input#openSlider').is(':checked')) {
        console.log('ture')
        $('.main--page__box').addClass("main__page--opened");
    } else {
        console.log('false')
        $('.main--page__box').removeClass("main__page--opened");
    }
});
```

When I close my drawer from `closeSidebar` function in `header.js`, the onChange of `Home.js` does not remove `removeClass(main__page--opened)`

What is the issue in here I couldn't find.
Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: After checking the input, than you have to trigger change event... `$('input#openSlider').prop('checked', false).trigger('change');`

Comment: @skobaljic in which file and where, I did not understand well. is it possible you to provide a code?

Comment: In header.js you do `$('input#openSlider').prop('checked', false);`, but it **does not trigger the change event** and you have to do it manually, using `$('input#openSlider').trigger('change')`. That way, your other script Home.js can catch the event.

Comment: @skobaljic I've edited my code just as your way still not working

Comment: Now you trigger change, but it is not checked... look at my first comment please: 1st do your prop change `$('input#openSlider').prop('checked', false);` than trigger the event `$('input#openSlider').trigger('change');` OR do them on same line `$('input#openSlider').prop('checked', false).trigger('change');`;

Comment: @skobaljic thanks mate now it's working :). thanks again for your effort